# Create standalone executable c++ embed Lua dymamic library link? (eclipse,ubuntu)

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, lua, executable

I create a c++ program and embedding Lua script. I use dynamic link to Lua library (not install Lua). In Lua file embedding i just print a message "Hello Lua". so how to i make standalone executable c++ embed Lua library and i can run it on other machine(ubuntu)?

Structure c++ project is:

```
HelloLua (project)
   includes: (static library)
   data
      helloLua.lua
   include
        lua: (lua.h,lua.hpp...)
   lib
      lua
         x86:liblua52.a,liblua52.0
   main
       main.cpp
```

and this is command build

```
make 
mkdir -p bin/x86
Compiling main/main.cpp ... done
Linking bin/x86/MyNguyen ... done.

> Target: MyNguyen (Arch: x86)
> Settings: g++ -pipe -m32 -O3 -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -D_REENTRANT -D_PASSTHRU_0404 -DX86_BUILD -DLINUX -LDFLAGS -DSOFTWARE_VERSION="'1.0.0'" 
> Libraries: -lm -Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl -llua52 
> strip bin/x86/MyNguyen ... done.

**** Build Finished ****
```

Answer (score 0):

The source code of lua is widely available. You can compile lua as part of your project, or use the dynamic libraries. In both cases you'll need some C++ initialization code.